# iOS native functionality inside a Titanium application

Tags: ios, ios4, titanium, titanium-modules, hybrid

I have a Titanium application and I want to put few UI screens which have been developed using iPhone SDK (native) inside it.

1. Titanium app starts and at some point it calls the native UI classes and the the native classes cotinue the navigation.
2. I need to switch back and forth accordingly as well.
3. Obviously I need to pass patameters between them.

Can these requirements be developed using iOS Module Development which can be found at [iOS Module Development- Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide)

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom module is the only way to do this besides re-writing your Obj-C code in Titanium.

Modules are really not that difficult! The link you provided is a great starting point, also I would [check the moddevguide example module](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules) which is chock full of examples of passing data back and forth.  Also, the paint module is a great example of subclassing UIView to roll your own titanium component.